# App got rejected in app store due to black screen in iOS 9.2.1

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I submitted the app on app store which supports iOS 7 and later with only portrait support for iPhone. We have launch images for both iPad and iPhone. We are doing everything programmatically and using Xcode7.2 . But apple rejected stating :

**We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on an iPad running iOS 9.2.1 and an iPhone running iOS 9.2.1 on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks.
- App boots to a black screen, no further action occurs.**

We did not came across this issue. Can anybody please help me in knowing what might be the issue.

Comment: if you have a device then update its os to 9.2.1 and then check.

Comment: whats your xcode version ?

Comment: @Vizllx : I have edited the question. Can u please check it.

Comment: @Signare : I have checked it in iPad mini running iOS 9.2.1 and no issue came. I got launch screen and then my root view controller. I have checked in all iPhone devices also. Can there be some issue from Apple?

Comment: @NirmalSinghMehra then you have to inform apple about this.

Comment: @NirmalSinghMehra my app also rejected due to fb problem with same version on ios 9.2.1 ,Then i appeal and added screenshot  just now i appeal you also try with appeal option.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is related to Facebook sdk. The facebook sdk had issue related to [FBSDKAppEvent activateApp] method. Check this link for more clear understanding :
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/change-log-4.x. So if we are using v4.8.0 sdk which was released on November 11, 2015 then it will have issue. The issue may not occur every time but it can occur. So replace the old Facebook sdk with newer version of Facebook sdk.

Answer (score 0):

It could also be due to targeting an app for iPhone only and using IF or SWITCH statements somewhere in the code to control the layout design (Full screen BG image, size of the view, etc.). The IF/SWITCH statements perhaps don't count on any other case of device than iPhone, so add one line to address this even for iPads. Something like this:

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage alloc];

if([[UIDevice currentDevice]userInterfaceIdiom]==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {

    switch ((int)[[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeBounds].size.height) {

        case 1136:
            printf("iPhone 5 or 5S or 5C");
            img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"];
            break;
        case 1334:
            printf("iPhone 6/6S/7/8");
            img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg1334.png"];
            break;
        case 2208:
            printf("iPhone 6+/6S+/7+/8+");
            img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg2208.png"];
            break;
        case 2436:
            printf("iPhone X");
            img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg-iPhone-X.png"];
            break;
        default:
            printf("unknown"); // -------------------  iPad issue solved!
            img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg1334.png"];
    }
}

UIImageView *bgImageV = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
bgImageV.frame = self.view.frame;
[self.view addSubview:bgImageV];

bgImageV.layer.zPosition = -15;
bgImageV.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
```